# Migrating from Hit/Hits to TopDocs/TopDocCollector

Tags: java, lucene

I have existing code that's like:

```
final Term t = /* ... */;
final Iterator i = searcher.search( new TermQuery( t ) ).iterator();
while ( i.hasNext() ) {
    Hit hit = (Hit)i.next();
    // "FILE" is the field that recorded the original file indexed
    File f = new File( hit.get( "FILE" ) );
    // ...
}
```

It's not clear to me how to rewrite the code using `TopDocs`/`TopDocCollector` and how to iterate over *all* results.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Basically, you have to decide on a limit to the number of results you expect. Then you iterate over all the `ScoreDoc`s in the resulting `TopDocs`.

```
final MAX_RESULTS = 10000;
final Term t = /* ... */;
final TopDocs topDocs = searcher.search( new TermQuery( t ), MAX_RESULTS );
for ( ScoreDoc scoreDoc : topDocs.scoreDocs ) {
    Document doc = searcher.doc( scoreDoc.doc )
    // "FILE" is the field that recorded the original file indexed
    File f = new File( doc.get( "FILE" ) );
    // ...
}
```

This is basically what the `Hits` class does, only it sets the limit at **50** results, and if you iterate past that, then the search is repeated, which is usually wasteful. That is why it was deprecated.

**ADDED**: If there isn't a limit you can put on the number of the results, you should use a HitCollector:

```
final Term t = /* ... */;
final ArrayList<Integer> docs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
searcher.search( new TermQuery( t ), new HitCollector() {
    public void collect(int doc, float score) {
        docs.add(doc);
    }
});

for(Integer docid : docs) {
    Document doc = searcher.doc(docid);
    // "FILE" is the field that recorded the original file indexed
    File f = new File( doc.get( "FILE" ) );
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Except I want all results.  (I want it to function more like grep.)